# WordPress - Admin nav menus page hangs

Tags: php, wordpress, server

I've got a weird one here, perhaps you've experienced this.

I've got a remotely hosted WordPress install that, when accessed from this computer only (my 2 immediate office mate neighbours verified), never loads the /wp-admin/nav-menus.php page.

The behaviour is literally a forever spinning wheel that never leaves the page you attempted to load from. It's never able to hit the page so it doesn't show any debug.

I've upped the php_max_vars from 1000 - 3000. No Luck.
Loading on my local MAMP server, this page loads without lag.
As mentioned, 2 computers in the same office can access and save this page.
I've rebooted.

Comment: Try clearing your cache, including any cookies, and turning off all browser plugins. Alternatively, try accessing it in your browser's incognito mode. Odds are you have a cookie, plugin, or userscript that is breaking the site.

Comment: Have you checked your error logs?

Comment: Sounds like you've hit a memory limit on your hosted platform. Disable all plugins and see whether it runs. If it's not a plugin issue, your theme has a performance issue